# python shelve key error

Tags: python, shelve

I pickled a few dictionaries using shelve module. Once, I decided to open  the file where data was pickled with Notepad++. There were cyrillic letters, so I tried to decode them with different encoders ( didn't succeed in it though ).
After that, I started getting error while running my python script:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Baysarov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'chrs'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    print(db['chrs']['Arma 2'])
  File "C:\Users\Baysarov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__
    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])
  File "C:\Users\Baysarov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\dbm\dumb.py", line 141, in __getitem__
    pos, siz = self._index[key]     # may raise KeyError
KeyError: b'chrs'
```

The same is with every other dictionary in the file.
Keys presence can be seen if I print:

```
>>> print(list(db.keys()))
['yb_imgs', 'chrs', 'gnames', 'plati_ids', 'tags', 'descrs']
```

Can it be fixed?

Comment: Notepad++ has probably written line-endings to the file, but it depends on how you saved it.  No backup?

Comment: I've got one, but it was created long ago.
I've forgotten to mention that the file grew in size after those manipulations with encoders

Comment: Maybe it is because that the shelve file is unintentionally modified by your code ---  the default open mode of shelve is not `r` but `c` (r/w & create new). (see doc https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)